# Applying pattern recognizing in java

Tags: java

I doing a image processing in Java. I would like to make a number recognition program.

I am thinking use what algorithm to apply the pattern recognition. I want to compare the similarity between the processed image (number 2) with number 2

[image: Processed image which is Number 2]

I searched internet and found that maybe can use city block similarity. Anyone can recommend me other suitable method?

Comment: There are entire libraries of books written on image recognition.  Go read them.

Comment: Thanks gilbert. I'm appreciate your help.